# How is it possible to return something to a function called by an Event Listener?

Tags: javascript, function, return, global-variables, addeventlistener

Is it possible to return the result of a function if it is called by an event listener? I  have tried lots of ways but nothing works. To my surprise there is not much information regarding it that can help me out. I would like to pass in the current score , increment it by one when an event occurs and return. Obviously what i have done below will not work because a) there is no storage for the return statement and b) it is called by an event listener. The only thing i am resorting to doing is changing my global variable inside the function. I know that wouldnt be as harmful if wrapped in an IIFE or its own closure but i still dont want to get in the habit of doing it. Is there anyway of incrementing the score by 1 and not referencing the global score variable inside the function directly, thanks all

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

let score = 0;

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {

    increaseScore(score); // passing in the current score varialble
})


function increaseScore(currentScore) { 

    currentScore++;
    return currentScore;      // there is nowhere to return this!!

}
```

Comment: `score = increaseScore(score)`. Really nothing to do with the event handler

Comment: yes i know i could do that but i only want the score to increase if the button is pressed ? Surely score = increaseScore(score) will call the function immediately and increase the score but i wouldnt want to do that ?

Comment: oh no , i deleted the last post in error that says i have things mixed up, so sorry, can you please repost ?

Comment: Makes no sense to return anything.... Why do you need to return anything? If you want the variable `score` to increase you should be doing something else since you are not updating the global variable. Not sure where you got the idea it is bad to update the global in the function.

Comment: Not inside the event handler it won't get called immediately, only when event occurs ....just add `score =` in front of the way you have it written now

Comment: epascarello. I am updating the global variable by returning the parameter inside my function to it surely ?

Comment: charlietfl , fantastic , sounds silly but i didnt know you could do that , i thought the anonoymous that i create after the event listenener can just call another function not have an expression in it, naieve of me to think that, thanks for claryfying

Comment: i thought your original advice was to call score = increaseScore(score) in the global context and not inside the event listenener, but yes this makes sense, thanks again

Comment: epascarello, In regards to updating global varialbes inside functions, My research warned me against this unless its inside a closure or something like an IIFE wrapper,  which can keep my variables private to the scope of the function otherwise if many people are working on the same script you could end up interfering with a global variable  meant for a different context. Although my programs are small, this is a habit im trying to get into, would you agree with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is you need to bind the context(this)

```
  someMethod.bind(this);
```

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const scoreBtn = document.querySelector('#score');

let score = 0;


btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  someMethod.bind(this);
  score = someMethod(score);
});

scoreBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(score);
});

function someMethod(cur) {
 return cur + 1; 
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Update Score</button>
<button id="score">Show Score</button>
```